# Hadoop: File … could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

**This is my error message.**

```
~/hadoop-1.0.3/data$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal README.txt /input/wex <br/>
~/hadoop-1.0.3/data$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal RandomString.txt /input/wex<br/>
~/hadoop-1.0.3/data$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal 2M.TITLE.ID /input/wex<br/>
~/hadoop-1.0.3/data$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal 2M.SRCID.DSTID /input/wex<br/>
~/hadoop-1.0.3/data$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal 10K.ID.CONTENTS /input/wex<br/>
~/hadoop-1.0.3/data$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal 2M.ID.CONTENTS /input/wex<br/>

14/11/30 17:57:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /input/wex/2M.ID.CONTENTS could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3510)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2829)
```

**As you can see, I failed at Big File only. (2M.ID.CONTENTS)**

```
ls -al
total 2710312<br\>
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu       4096 Jan  4  2013 .<br/>
drwxr-xr-x 17 ubuntu ubuntu       4096 Nov 30 16:42 ..<br/>
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    9735683 Sep 24  2012 10K.ID.CONTENT<br/>
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 2506926541 Sep 24  2012 2M.ID.CONTENTS<br/>
-rwxrwxr-x  1 ubuntu ubuntu  151641370 Aug  8  2012 2M.SRCID.DSTID<br/>
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   73550219 Jul 25  2012 2M.TITLE.ID<br/>
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu   33481780 Aug  9  2012 RandomString.txt<br/>
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu       1366 Sep 23  2012 README.txt<br/>
```

**I have tried the followings :**

1) I checked `hadoop.tmp.dir` directory privilege.
   2) I restart all hadoop processes (include re-format namenode) several times.
   3) I changed `hadoop.tmp.dir` from `/tmp/my-user-name/dfs/data` to `/home/my-user-name/data/hdfstmp`.

**Why can't I upload big file to HDFS?**

Comment: Have you checked there is enough space? Somehow it fails to create an additional block.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your hadoop cluster is running; but it does not see the data nodes. Can you check if the datanode is running or not by
1. running the command jps your terminal. You have to see the datanode and namenode active
2. if you installed your hadoop on a ubuntu machine (not EC2), go to your browser and try this address `http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp` you have to see `live node =1` and `not zero`. If it is zero, that means that there is an installation problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I success on copying above five files. I failed only one big file. And I can see all hadoop processes include datanode using 'jps' command.

Comment: Did you try the hadoop fs -put command? and did it give the same results?